# renci.sshnet - how to type a text in ssh session

Tags: c#, ssh

using Renci.SshNet;

```
var conn = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host , user, pass);
                using (var client = new SshClient (conn) )
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    client.RunCommand("echo type A; read letter; echo you typed $letter");
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
```

simple example which asks user for prompt. It "hangs" because waits for user response. How this response implement in C#?

Answer (score 2):

well, I guess my question was not clear enough that's why I had no answers. Anyway I had to help myself and finally I found out what to do. Maybe the answer help somebody

Instead of using **SshClient** more suitable is **ShellStream**.

The code below is just a hint - not a ready solution but it is a good start :)

```
  using (var client = new SshClient (conn) )
        {
            client.Connect();
            ShellStream shells = client.CreateShellStream("test", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
            shells.WriteLine("echo Type letter A please");
            shells.WriteLine("read letter");
            shells.WriteLine("A");
            shells.WriteLine("echo $letter");
            string output = shells.Read();
        }
```